# on Android is there any idea how to play next item using setOnCompletionListener

Tags: java, android

I trying to develop the mediaplayer apps, i using listview to display and play the song,
I have problem with play automatically the next sound (item) using setOnCompletionListener

My code :

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                final int position, long id) {

            mButtonPause.setEnabled(true);
            mButtonResume.setEnabled(false);

            if (position == 0){
                sound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                String audioUrl1 = "https://embeye.tech/ummi/speaker/0001.mp3";
                try {

                    halaman.setText("Doa Pembuka");

                    playSound(audioUrl1);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    mButtonNext.setEnabled(true);
                    mButtonPrev.setEnabled(false);

                    initializeSeekBar();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (SecurityException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IllegalStateException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else if (position == 1) {
                sound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                String audioUrl1 = "https://embeye.tech/ummi/speaker/jilidsatu/0101.mp3";
                try {

                    halaman.setText("Halaman Satu");
                    playSound(audioUrl1);

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    initializeSeekBar();

                    mButtonNext.setEnabled(true);
                    mButtonPrev.setEnabled(true);

                }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (SecurityException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IllegalStateException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else if (position == 2){
                sound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                String audioUrl1 = "https://embeye.tech/ummi/speaker/jilidsatu/0102.mp3";
                try {
                    halaman.setText("Halaman Dua");
                    playSound(audioUrl1);

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    initializeSeekBar();

                    mButtonNext.setEnabled(true);
                    mButtonPrev.setEnabled(true);

                }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (SecurityException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IllegalStateException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else if (position == 3){
                sound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                String audioUrl1 = "https://embeye.tech/ummi/speaker/jilidsatu/0103.mp3";
                try {

                    halaman.setText("Halaman Tiga");
                    playSound(audioUrl1);

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    initializeSeekBar();

                    mButtonNext.setEnabled(true);
                    mButtonPrev.setEnabled(true);

                }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (SecurityException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IllegalStateException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            sound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"End",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mButtonResume.setEnabled(true);
                    sound.isPlaying();
                    sound.reset();
                    songNumber = String.valueOf(position + 1);

                    sound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    String audioUrl1 = songNumber;
                    playSound(audioUrl1);
                }
            });
        }


    });
```

the error i got from logcat :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array

but actually i have define that on the songNumber :

```
            sound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"End",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mButtonResume.setEnabled(true);
                    sound.isPlaying();
                    sound.reset();
                    songNumber = String.valueOf(position + 1);

                    sound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    String audioUrl1 = songNumber;
                    playSound(audioUrl1);
                }
            });
```

What actually i want to do is i would like to play the next song when the current song completed, based on my code above, i would like to activate "postion == 1" when "position == 0" complete

Answer (score 0):

`songNumber = String.valueOf(position + 1);` means that songNumber will be "2", and as you're setting the audioUrls to be "2".

I'd suggest you to make an `Array` of audioUrls, and then set `songNumber = audioUrls.get(++position);`

If that doesn't help you, you could post the full stacktrace so we could see the actual error.

Comment: hi @isaaaaame thank for your comment, little bit confuse here, What actually i want to do is i would like to play the next song when the current song completed, based on my code above, i would like to activate "postion == 1" when "position == 0" complete